# Stream Java Max Comparator

Tags: java, max, java-stream, comparator

This is the code that returns the object that has the maximum date starting from a stream, I would like to return a list to me, assuming that there are more records.

How should it be changed?

```
Comparator<DatoStoricoNominativo> comparator = 
                   Comparator.comparing( DatoStoricoNominativo::getDataFine );
DatoStoricoNominativo dsna = dsn.stream().max(comparator).get();
```

Comment: *I would like to return a list to me* -- List of what?

Answer (score 0):

You can do another iteration to find out the elements that have same date as `dsna`, e.g.:

```
List< DatoStoricoNominativo> elements = dsn.stream()
              .filter(e -> dsna.getDataFine().equals(e.getDataFine())
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```